# ActionBarSherlock and Another Project's Have Conflicting Support Version 4

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is an error I know how to fix but its getting really annoying and happening every time close and then open eclipse again. I am in the process of making an Android app that uses the Action Sherlock library. I imported Action Sherlock into my workspace and my other project sees it as a library on its build path. However to successfully run my application and not get an error relating to a Jar Mismatch!, I need to uncheck the support version 4 contained from the Order and Export screen in the Action Sherlock project. After this the app runs successfully and works fine. However, if I close Eclipse and then open it, it seems like the build path somehow resets itself!? The support version 4 library that I had previous unchecked in the Action Sherlock project is checked again. Because of this the project won't run.

Is this some kind of a bug in Eclipse? I guess I could always delete the support library in Action Sherlock but I'm afraid to do this as it will break my app. Has anyone ever ran into this problem before or am I the only one?

Any answers or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to copy your version of the support library over ActionBarSherlock's without any trouble. Then it won't matter if you check order and export because there won't be any conflicts between the jars.

Comment: Yes this solution worked. I rebuilt everything and now there is no error since the support libraries are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Either delete the supportv4.jar from your project and use the one bundled in ActionBarSherlock, or update the supportv4.jar in ActionbarSherlock and then delete the one in your project. You see, the conflict arises because with ActionBarSherlock comes a version of the supportv4.jar, so your classpath has two versions of the same jar.